# WearableDrawerView peek view example

Tags: android, user-interface, wear-os

Could someone please help with a working sample of of **WearableDrawerView** to create a ***peekview*** for the android wear app.

I tried the one suggested in https://developer.android.com/wear/preview/features/ui-nav-actions.html . But it ***doesn't work.***

Appreciate your help.

Comment: What does your error logs say?